# AWS Sagemaker Error for Training job - Algorithm Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am receiving the following error when I try and train an XGBoost model and have no idea how to fix it. Any help please?

```
UnexpectedStatusException: Error for Training job sagemaker-xgboost-2022-08-22-21-37-39-774: Failed. Reason: AlgorithmError: framework error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_containers/_trainer.py", line 84, in train
    entrypoint()
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_xgboost_container/training.py", line 94, in main
    train(framework.training_env())
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_xgboost_container/training.py", line 90, in train
    run_algorithm_mode()
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_xgboost_container/training.py", line 68, in run_algorithm_mode
    checkpoint_config=checkpoint_config
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_xgboost_container/algorithm_mode/train.py", line 110, in sagemaker_train
    validated_train_config = hyperparameters.validate(train_config)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_algorithm_toolkit/hyperparameter_validation.py", line 270, in validate
    raise exc.UserError("Missing required hyperparameter: {}".format(hp)
```

My full notebook is too large to post here, but below I have also added an image of the code right before the training

[image]

Answer (score 1):

SageMaker's implementation of XGBoost requires one hyperparameter, all other parameters are optional, looks like you are not passing the required parameter, `num_round`.
Try adding this to your dictionary:

```
hyperparameters = {
     "num_round": 10
}
```

***Per AWS docs, num_round: The number of rounds to run the training. Valid values: integer***

For more information on SageMaker's hyperparameters requirements refer to: [SageMaker Dev Guide: XGBoost Hyperparameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/xgboost_hyperparameters.html)